# detecting when 2 nodes intersect on every axis

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to write a simple game where you score by tapping when a ring (that is constantly getting larger and smaller) is inside a stationary ring however I can not figure out how to detect when the two nodes intersect or when the moving ring is inside the stationary ring. Can someone please show me how I could add to a score if someone tapped while the two nodes were the same size or if the moving node was inside the stationary node.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var Circle = SKSpriteNode()
    var Circle2 = SKSpriteNode()

    var GameStarted:Bool = false

    var Path = UIBezierPath()
    var run1 = false
    var called = true
    var intersected = false


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        Circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle")
        Circle.size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        Circle.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        self.addChild(Circle)
        Circle2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Circle2")
        Circle2.size = CGSize(width: 760, height: 760)
        Circle2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        self.addChild(Circle2)
        Circle.zPosition = 0.1
        Circle2.zPosition = 0.2
        var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 15, y: 15), radius: CGFloat(10), startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(2*Double.pi), clockwise: true)
        UIColor.blue.setStroke()    
    }



    func scaleCircle2(){
        let duration = 5.0
        let scaleAction2 = SKAction.scale(to: CGSize(width: 760, height: 760), duration: TimeInterval(duration))
        let scaleAction = SKAction.scale(to: CGSize(width: 15, height: 15), duration: TimeInterval(duration))
        let pulse = SKAction.sequence([scaleAction,scaleAction2])
        let forever = SKAction.repeatForever(pulse)
        Circle2.run(forever)


   }



    func scaleCircleUP(){
        let duration2 = 0.5
        let initialsize = 100
        let scaleAction3 = SKAction.scale(to: CGSize(width: initialsize + 100, height: initialsize + 100), duration: TimeInterval(duration2))
        Circle.run(scaleAction3)

    }



    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        GameStarted = true
        if GameStarted == true{
            callCircle2()
        }
    }


    func callCircle2(){    //makes sure scaleCircle2 isn't called twice
        if called == true{
            scaleCircle2()
        }
        called = false
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

When determining whether one circular object is in another larger circular object, you simply compare the absolute value of the difference of their radius to the distance between their center.

```
extension CGPoint {
    func distanceTo(_ p:CGPoint) -> CGFloat {
        return sqrt(pow((p.x - x), 2) + pow((p.y - y), 2))
    }
}

let dist = Float(Circle.position.distanceTo(Circle2.position))
let radiusDiff = fabsf(Float((Circle.size.width - Circle2.size.width))
if dist < radiusDiff {
    // smaller circle is in larger circle
}
```

In your case, seems like you never move their origins and you knew which object would be the "smaller" one, simply compare their radius.